# Why glass always breaks into sharp pieces?

Tags: everyday-life, material-science, glass

I understand that common glass and pottery (though not, for example, the glass of a car's windscreen) breaks very easily because it is very brittle and it has a great number of "cracks" in its structure.

But why sharp corners are always formed?

Comment: @Naptzer That comment could make a nice answer

Comment: Sure can do ! (wanted to edit my comment but ended up deleting it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ordinary glass has an irregular '[amorphous' molecular structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_solid). That means that every pane has a unique, random 'fingerprint' of weak points, at which the glass might shatter.

When it shatters, it breaks along lines connecting the weak points. Sharp-edged polygons are the inevitable result of cracking along random lines on a pane of glass.

However, [modern 'tempered' glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toughened_glass) may be engineered for safety. It cracks into something resembling gravel, that isn't that sharp and won't cause deep cuts. Have you ever seen a vandalized telephone box or bus shelter? If so, you may have noticed the glassy gravel formed by the smashed glass.

Comment: So you're saying that since there are a finite number of weak(est) points, lines between them form when breaking?

Answer (score 2):

Say you have a piece of glass which is a thick surface (this is the case for drinking glasses, lightbulbs, window glasses...) that you break. Necessarily with every smooth piece there is a sharp piece that comes with it. Or you could say that the pieces must fit one another in the end, and the convex (smooth) part produces a concave (sharp) part :

[image]

There may be an explanation on the microscopic scale, and this is probably not enough. If someone has an answer I would also be interested in that !

Comment: Whenever I've broken glass, it didn't break into convex and matching concave pieces. It broke into jagged shards/polygons.

Comment: Yes but what I meant is that there is two options (I take the example of the breaking in two pieces wlog) : you have either 2 matching sharp pieces or 1 smooth and 1 sharp. It occurs to me that in the end you cannot have only smooth pieces

Comment: Ah, ok, i agree